# sencha touch:dynamically add/remove components to panels

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

i extended a panel containing

```
-Panel 
   -Toolbar with button
```

and i registered it as a xtype using Ext.reg().There is one more panel in which i want to add the registered xtype and did it. How can i add/remove a component/html content dynamically to the outer panel on button click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you :

```
var component = ...;
var position = 0;
component.insert(position, new Ext.Panel({html : "inserted"}));
component.doComponentLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks Santana for your response :) It was a bit tricky calculation of height with setHeight() and hide() methods.With the help of debugger i resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

While an older question, you can use .add or .addDocked

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-add

This is far simpler since it allows the panel to add the element and manage the height ect.